# Updating in mysql code for edit form

Tags: php, mysql, html, where-clause

```
<?php
ob_start();
include ('include/config_db.php');
//include ('include/header.php');
//include ('include/sidebar.php');

  $pro_id = $_REQUEST['pro_id'];

    $product_query= mysql_query("select * from product where pro_id='$pro_id'");
    $product_fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($product_query);

   if(isset($_REQUEST['save']))
   {
           $sub_id = $_REQUEST['sub_id'];
           $cat_id=  $_REQUEST['abc'];

           $pro_name = $_REQUEST['pro_name'];
           $pro_desc = $_REQUEST['pro_desc'];
           $pro_price = $_REQUEST['pro_price'];
           $pro_quant = $_REQUEST['pro_quant'];
           $pro_offer = $_REQUEST['pro_offer'];

             $product_query = mysql_query("update product set sub_id = '$sub_id' , cat_id = '$cat_id' ,pro_name = '$pro_name',pro_desc = '$pro_desc', pro_price = '$pro_price' , pro_quant = '$pro_quant' , pro_offer = '$pro_offer' where pro_id = $pro_id ");             

           if(!$sql)
           {
               die("User Is Not Update ". mysql_error());   
           } 

          header("Location: products.php");

   }

?> 

      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
          <h1>

            Edit Product Details Here.
          </h1>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
          <div class="row">
            <!-- left column -->
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <!-- general form elements -->
              <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                  <h3 class="box-title">Edit Product</h3>
                </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                <!-- form start -->
                  <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                  <div class="box-body">

                      <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label ">Category</label>
                              <div class="col-sm-6">

                                 <select class="form-control" onChange="get_subcat(this.value)" name="abc">

      <option value=""> Select Category </option>
                                    <?php

                                    $cat=mysql_query("select * from category"); 
                                    while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($cat))
                                        {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $fetch['cat_id'];?>" 
                                        <?php if( $fetch['cat_id'] == $product_fetch['cat_id'] )  { echo "selected"; }?> >
                                        <?php echo  $fetch['cat_name'];?>

                                    </option>

                                    <?php
                                                }
                                    ?>
                                </select>

                             </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                      <label for="inputText" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Sub Category Name</label>    

                      <div class="col-sm-6">

                         <select class="form-control" id="sub_id" name="sub_id" type="text">
                                    <?php
                                        $sub_category = mysql_query("select * from sub_category where cat_id = ".$product_fetch['cat_id']);
                                        while($sub_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($sub_category))
                                        {
                                    ?>
                      <option ><?php  echo $sub_fetch['sub_name']; ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                        </select>

                      </div>

                    </div>

                   <div class="form-group">
                        <label  class="col-sm-4 control-label">Product Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputtext" placeholder="Enter Product Name" required
                          name="pro_name" value="<?php echo $product_fetch['pro_name']; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label  class="col-sm-4 control-label">Product Description </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputtext" placeholder="Enter Product Description" required
                          name="pro_desc" value=<?php echo $product_fetch['pro_desc']; ?> >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label  class="col-sm-4 control-label">Product Price</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputtext" placeholder="Enter Product Price" required
                          name="pro_price" value=<?php echo $product_fetch['pro_price']; ?> >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label  class="col-sm-4 control-label">Total Product Quantity</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputtext" placeholder="Enter Product Quantity" required
                          name="pro_quant" value=<?php echo $product_fetch['pro_quant']; ?>>
                        </div>
                    </div>                      

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label  class="col-sm-4 control-label">Product Discount</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <select class="form-control" name="pro_offer">                                    

                              <option <?php if( $product_fetch['pro_offer'] == "10%") { echo "selected";} ?> >10%</option>
                              <option <?php if( $product_fetch['pro_offer'] == "20%") { echo "selected";} ?> >20%</option>
                              <option <?php if( $product_fetch['pro_offer'] == "30%") { echo "selected";} ?> >30%</option>
                              <option <?php if( $product_fetch['pro_offer'] == "40%") { echo "selected";} ?> >40%</option>
                              <option <?php if( $product_fetch['pro_offer'] == "50%") { echo "selected";} ?> >50%</option>
                              <option <?php if( $product_fetch['pro_offer'] == "60%") { echo "selected";} ?> > 60%</option>
                              <option <?php if( $product_fetch['pro_offer'] == "70%") { echo "selected";} ?> > 70%</option>
                              <option <?php if( $product_fetch['pro_offer'] == "80%") { echo "selected";} ?> >80%</option>
                              <option <?php if( $product_fetch['pro_offer'] == "90%") { echo "selected";} ?> > 90%</option>
                              <option <?php if( $product_fetch['pro_offer'] == "100%") { echo "selected";} ?> > 100%</option>
                              </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                  </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                  <div class="box-footer">
                    <a href="products.php"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button></a>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" name="save">Save Changes</button>
                  </div><!-- /.box-footer -->
                </form>
              </div><!-- /.box -->
             </div>
             </div>
             </section>
      </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->

<?php 

include ('include/footer.php');
ob_flush();
?>
```

In the whole operation of updating this error is coming as output:

> User Is Not Update Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`ayur`.`product`, CONSTRAINT `foreign_sub_id`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`sub_id`) REFERENCES `sub_category` (`sub_id`) ON DELETE
>   CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE).

Please, help me as sooon as possible to solve this query !!

Comment: The problem is not the code, but a foreign key constraint in the database. You need to check the values that you are trying to modify / put in the database because now they don't meet the requirements.

Comment: what value you try to update that is not available in reference table